# Existence of subspace disjoint from manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a differentiable $m$-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $m < n$. For $s < n − m$, I would like to show there is an $s$-dimensional affine subspace $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\cap M=\emptyset$. Also, what happens for $s=n-m$?

 I am not really sure where to start. Intuitively, I can understand that for instance, if you have a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, say, then you can find a curve which does not intersect that surface.

Comment: Do you know about transverality? That's the best way to phrase such problems.

Comment: Yes, I know what transversality is, but I am not sure how to phrase the problem.

Comment: Consider the space of $s$-dimensional affine subspaces. (You can parametrize by $s$ linearly independent vectors and a translation vector in $\Bbb R^n$.) The transversality theorem will tell you that the inclusion map of $M$ will be transverse to almost every such subspace. With your dimensions, transversality has to be by default (i.e., intersection is empty).

Comment: To add another reference to Ted's comments: check out Sard's theorem, which is often used to prove transversality results of this kind.

Comment: You should explain what do you already know about such results. Did you try to construct a counter example in the equality case (when $M$ is a curve in the plane).  People suggested Sard/transversality. Do you know what they are talking about? If not, how good is your real analysis? Can you prove that if $M$ is an $m$-dimensional manifold, $n>m$ and $f: M\to R^n$ is a smooth map, then $f(M)$ has zero measure?